# How to connect multiple micro-controllers' USB ports on the same PCB?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, usb, programming, interface

I'm designing a PCB with 3 Atmel ATmega16U4-AU micro-controllers on it.

I will be programming them through SPI.

Therefore, I will not be using D+ and D- ports on the USB interface. Then how do I deal with those pins.

Shall I:

1. Leave them unconnected?
2. Or Connect them to three different usb ports? (This way looks stupid. I don't want so many usb ports on the PCB)

Comment: Why are you using such a sophisticated chip if you're not using one of the largest selling points for it?

Comment: @Ignacio  Once, I've selected a PIC with USB because it happened to have the most Flash and RAM in its family.  I didn't need the USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the pins unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

With pretty much any modern micro, unless explicitly stated in the manual, unused IO can be left unconnected